# SQL- How can I exclude Groupings with a NULL value in the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to exclude groupings that contain a NULL Value from my results. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
FROM Appointment
WHERE EmployeeID IN
    (SELECT EmployeeID 
            FROM Appointment
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
GROUP BY EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

The result set looks something like this:

```
EmployeeID  AppointmentEndDate
1   NULL
1   2000-06-30 00:00:00.000
2   NULL
2   2006-06-30 00:00:00.000
2   2014-06-30 00:00:00.000
3   2006-07-02 00:00:00.000
3   2015-06-30 00:00:00.000
5   NULL
5   2001-12-31 00:00:00.000
5   2002-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

So in this particular instance I would only like to see records for EmployeeID 3

Much Gratitude,
A

Comment: Why not just filter out the rows with null using a WHERE clause?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used (main query).

Comment: I tried that but instead of filtering the ID's out it only filters the records that have a NULL, I want the entire group excluded. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: By group, you mean the "employee"?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your query to get unique employeeId's who never have appointment date as NULL in table

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM Appointment
WHERE AppointmentEndDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

or you can use distinct if you are not concerned whether the employeeIds with not null are occuring more than one time in table

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID
FROM Appointment
WHERE AppointmentEndDate IS NOT NULL
```

GROUP BY will help you use aggregate functions if you want like get last appointment date of employeeIds

```
SELECT EmployeeID , MAX(AppointmentEndDate) as LastDateOfAppointment
FROM Appointment
WHERE AppointmentEndDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(

    YourQueryHere

)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE AS x WHERE x.EmployeeID=CTE.EmployeeID AND AppointmentEndDate IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a "WHERE NOT EXISTS [Subselect]" to filter out employee that have one or many record with null AppointementEndDate. Assuming this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
FROM Appointment
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 
                 FROM Appointment AS A 
                 WHERE Appointment.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID
                 AND A.AppointmentEndDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You Should Try This It's Working.....

SELECT EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
FROM Appointment
WHERE EmployeeID NOT IN
    (SELECT EmployeeID 
            FROM Appointment
    WHERE AppointmentEndDate IS NULL
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
      )
GROUP BY EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what value the GROUP BY offers, but I left it in just in case this is a thinned down example.

```
Declare @Appointment table (EmployeeID int,AppointmentEndDate DateTime)
Insert Into @Appointment values
(1,NULL),
(1,'2000-06-30 00:00:00.000'),
(2,NULL),
(2,'2006-06-30 00:00:00.000'),
(2,'2014-06-30 00:00:00.000'),
(3,'2006-07-02 00:00:00.000'),
(3,'2015-06-30 00:00:00.000'),
(5,NULL),
(5,'2001-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
(5,'2002-06-30 00:00:00.000')

Select EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
 From  @Appointment
 Where EmployeeID NOT IN (Select Distinct EmployeeID From @Appointment Where AppointmentEndDate Is NULL )
 Group By EmployeeID,AppointmentEndDate
 Order ByEmployeeID
```

Returns

```
EmployeeID  AppointmentEndDate
3           2006-07-02 00:00:00.000
3           2015-06-30 00:00:00.000
```